# How to improve the readablity of this graph of multiple series with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I have several curves on either side of the x-axis (like the green and orange curve in my case) what would be the best way to improve the display of this graph, for a better reading?

I was thinking for example by integrating a zoomed part on the curves between 0 and 0.15s on the x-axis.

Also each value of the curves correspond to a number, represented by a different marker (square, triangle, circle..) on the curves. Is there a better way to represent these curves and display these markers? In a slightly cleaner and more scientific way.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = [0.807, 0.633, 0.416, 0.274, 0.188]
time_A = [0.0990, 0.1021, 0.1097, 0.1109, 0.1321]

B = [0.764, 0.753, 0.716, 0.576, 0.516]
time_B = [0.1727, 0.1742, 0.1772, 0.1869, 0.1765]

C = [0.729, 0.719, 0.674, 0.631, 0.616]
time_C = [0.5295, 0.5368, 0.5431, 0.5391, 0.5443]

E = [0.709, 0.605, 0.390, 0.259, 0.155]
time_E = [0.0829, 0.0929, 0.0910, 0.0950, 0.0972]

D = [0.703, 0.541, 0.174, 0.062, 0.020]
time_D = [0.0740, 0.0792, 0.0819,  0.0837, 0.0858]

F = [0.748, 0.566, 0.366, 0.198, 0.168]
time_F = [0.0885, 0.0936, 0.09621, 0.0974, 0.0999]

markers = ["s", "^", "o", 'p', '*']

plt.plot(time_A, A, c='tab:blue', 
         label='A')

plt.plot(time_B, B, c='tab:red', 
         label='B')

plt.plot(time_C, C, c='tab:orange',
         label='C')

plt.plot(time_D, D, c='tab:green',
         label='D')

plt.plot(time_E, E, c='yellow',
         label='E')
 
plt.plot(time_F, F, c='tab:cyan',
         label='F')

for i in range(5):

    plt.plot(time_A[i], A[i], c='tab:blue',
             marker=markers[i], markersize=7)

    plt.plot(time_B[i], B[i], c='tab:red',
            marker=markers[i], markersize=7)

    plt.plot(time_C[i], C[i], c='tab:orange',
             marker=markers[i], markersize=7)

    plt.plot(time_D[i], D[i], c='tab:green',
             marker=markers[i], markersize=7)

    plt.plot(time_E[i], E[i], c='yellow',
             marker=markers[i], markersize=7)

    plt.plot(time_F[i], F[i],  c='tab:cyan',
             marker=markers[i], markersize=7)

textstr = '\n'.join((
    f'\u25A0 1',
    f'\u25B2 2',
    f'\u25CF 3',
    f'\u2B1F 4',
    f'\u2605 5'))

plt.text(0.4, 0.5, textstr,
         verticalalignment='top', fontsize = 'small') 

plt.legend(fontsize = 'small')

plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('score')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Below is the result with the broken axis between 0.2 and 0.5 according to the comments. What is the correct way to integrate markers into curves with matplotlib?

[image]

Comment: Could you make the X axis logarithmic.   It looks like that would spread the curves out more evenly over the range.

Comment: You can use a [broken axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html) to bridge the gap between 0.2 and 0.5. See also [this project](https://github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes) for a higher level API.

Comment: Opinion based questions are off-topic: _This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers._ [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) & [Don't advise on off-topic questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/)

Comment: @a_guest Thank you for your suggestion I tried it and I edited the post. Do you have an idea for the markers?

Comment: @JohanC I'm not sure about the dotted line, do you have a sample code?

Comment: plotly would be interactive

Comment: Why do you manually plot the legend? (`plt.text(0.4, 0.5, textstr...`)? Is it to manually control its x,y placement to be inside the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

- use a dummy line to add labels for the markers; use two columns for the legend
- set a log scale on the x-axis, but with regular tick labels
- connect the markers of the same style with a fine line (order the points left to right for the line not to cross itself)
- use the color 'gold' instead of 'yellow' to make it better visible
- write everything as much as possible using loops

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter, ScalarFormatter, FixedLocator
import numpy as np

A = [0.807, 0.633, 0.416, 0.274, 0.188]
time_A = [0.0990, 0.1021, 0.1097, 0.1109, 0.1321]
B = [0.764, 0.753, 0.716, 0.576, 0.516]
time_B = [0.1727, 0.1742, 0.1772, 0.1869, 0.1765]
C = [0.729, 0.719, 0.674, 0.631, 0.616]
time_C = [0.5295, 0.5368, 0.5431, 0.5391, 0.5443]
E = [0.709, 0.605, 0.390, 0.259, 0.155]
time_E = [0.0829, 0.0929, 0.0910, 0.0950, 0.0972]
D = [0.703, 0.541, 0.174, 0.062, 0.020]
time_D = [0.0740, 0.0792, 0.0819, 0.0837, 0.0858]
F = [0.748, 0.566, 0.366, 0.198, 0.168]
time_F = [0.0885, 0.0936, 0.09621, 0.0974, 0.0999]

names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
times = [time_A, time_B, time_C, time_D, time_E, time_F]
scores = [A, B, C, D, E, F]

markers = ["s", "^", "o", 'p', '*']
colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green', 'gold', 'tab:cyan']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
for time, score, name, color in zip(times, scores, names, colors):
    ax.plot(time, score, c=color, label=name)

for i in range(len(scores[0])):
    ax.plot([], [], color='black', ls='', marker=markers[i], markersize=7, label=i + 1)
    for time, score, name, color in zip(times, scores, names, colors):
        ax.plot(time[i], score[i], color=color, marker=markers[i], markersize=7)
    time_i = np.array([time[i] for time in times])
    score_i = np.array([score[i] for score in scores])
    order = np.argsort(time_i)
    ax.plot(time_i[order], score_i[order], color='grey', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.5, zorder=0)

ax.legend(fontsize='small', ncol=2)
ax.set_xscale('log')
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0.1, round(xmax, 1), 0.1))
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(round(xmin, 2), round(xmax, 1), 0.01), minor=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
ax.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax.set_ylabel('score')
plt.show()
```

[image: line plot with markers and updated legend]

If the values of the x-ticks are very important, the minor ticks could also get labels, for example:

```py
minor_formatter = lambda x, pos: f'{x:.2f}' if (x < .1) or (x < .2 and round(100 * x) % 2 == 0) or (
        x > .2 and round(100 * x) % 10 == 5) else ''
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(minor_formatter)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', size=6, labelcolor='grey')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', size=12)
```

[image: labeling some of the minor x ticks]